# Proving a sum divergent

Tags: analysis

Hello I am solving the following problem.

> Define a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ as follows: Let $a_1$ be any real number
> satisfying $0 < a_1 < 1$, and define $a_2, a_3,\dots$ recursively via $a_{n+1} := \cos(a_n)$ . Prove the series $\sum_n a_n$ is divergent.

Using Banachs fixed point theorem I have proven that $(a_n)$ is convergent. I am confused on how to prove the latter.

Answer (score 3):

All that is needed is to show that the limit of the $a_n$ is nonzero.

Comment: so does this mean to write out the terms of the sequence?

Comment: @LavoriziaVaughn Under the assumption that $\langle a_n\rangle$ is convergent, it will have to converge to the root of the equation $\cos(x) = x ~: 0 < x < \pi/2$.  The root of this equation is non-zero.

Comment: More precisely, we only need to show that $a_n$ does not converge to $0$.  So we are free to assume that $a_n$ converges since otherwise that is already true.